# R match value to column based on column (tricky)

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe like this one:

```
label1 label2 label3
5      3      2
4.1    5      4
2      1      3
```

I want to add a new column based on the condition:

1. Match column header if value is greater than 4
2. The max value out of the three if two or more values are greater than 4

So the resulting df would look like:

```
label1 label2 label3 Match
5      3      2      label1
4.1    5      4      label2
2      1      3      none

So for the first row 5 is greater than 4 so label1
For the second row label2 as it is the highest (two values higher than 4)
For the third none as all values are below 4
```

This seems tricky with R as with Excel with max + if functions can be done.

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `max.col` to get the index of row with max value. If there is no value greater than 4 in a row we change `match` value to `'none'` for those rows.

```
df1$match <- paste0('label', max.col(df1))
df1$match[rowSums(df1[-ncol(df1)] > 4) == 0] <- 'none'

df1
#  label1 label2 label3  match
#1    5.0      3      2 label1
#2    4.1      5      4 label2
#3    2.0      1      3   none
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(label1 = c(5, 4.1, 2), label2 = c(3L, 5L, 1L), 
label3 = c(2L, 4L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))
```